# send object as function parameter

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery script:

```
var deleteRow
$('.myBtnA').click(function() {
    deleteRow = $(this).closest('tr')
    showModal("delete(deleteRow)")
});
```

This works. myBtnB shows like this:

```
<button type="button" class="myBtnB" onclick="delete(deleteRow)"></button>
```

But I would like to work without the var deleteRow.
I tried this:

```
$('.myBtnA').click(function() {
    showModal("delete(" + $(this).closest('tr') +")")
});
```

But now it fails:

```
<button type="button" class="myBtnB" onclick="deleteInvoice([object Object])"></button>
```

Where is my mistake? :(

Comment: Whats the error

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'Object'. Expected either a closing ']' or a ',' following an array element.

Comment: If you are attaching jQuery event handlers, why are you using inline `onclick` attributes at all? The problem seems moot.

Comment: The error lies in the way you implement onclick event: inline tag and  event listener at the same time make no sense

Comment: Absolutely Rory is too right `onclick` is for Javascript why are you mixing both

Comment: Sound like you're trying to fix an [x/y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Could you please add more details / a [mre]?

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding. I have btnA, which calls the onclick event and will set an onclick function for btnB. I updated my first post

Comment: You need to show what your "delete" function do

Comment: There are much better ways to amend the behaviour of one button based on the action of another, delegated event handlers with data attributes, for example. I'd suggest starting a new question providing details of your actual goal, and including a description of why you need button A to affect button B. Currently this is an X/Y question, as @0stone0 points out.